# Missing required argument

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Just updated to 2.3.0 and when i try to open Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods i get following error:

> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument
>   $version of Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext.

How can i solve it?

Comment: is it fresh magento installation?

Comment: @SohelRana No, it's not. I just updated from 2.1.7 to 2.3.0